# Regex command line argument is expanded

Tags: bash, command-line, regular-expression, arguments

I am trying to pass a regex pattern as an argument to my script as follows:

`bash script.sh '[a-z]*[0-9]*'`

in my script I am assigning it to a variable

`FIRST_ARG=$1`

using `echo $FIRST_ARG` results in showing the files that match the expression, (i.e `text1.txt`, `file2.txt`.

I want the `$1` to stay `[a-z]*[0-9]*`, I tried wrapping every variable with double quotes and without quotes and that didn't work, I also tried using single quotes, double quotes and no quotes on the command line argument and it doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: When you run `echo $1`, the shell will expand the glob (your regex pattern is treated as a glob in this context), and that's why you see the matching files. You need to always quote your variables, so use `echo "$FIRST_ARG"` or, even better, `printf '%s\n' -- "$FIRST_ARG"`, and it will work as expected.

Comment: I realized what I've done after posting the question, I've been looking online for hours trying to get an answer lol, not my best day.

Comment: No worries, this sort of thing confuses all of us until we get used to it! Read the answers to the duplicate, they have some really good info.